# how to make nodejs exports a static object

Tags: node.js

i wonder to know is the code below runs right

a.js:

```
var obj = {
    name: 'a'
};
module.exports = obj;
```

b.js

```
var b = require('./a');

module.exports = b;
```

c.js

```
var a = require('./a');

console.log(a); // {name: 'a'}

a.name = 'b';
console.log(require('./a')); // {name: 'b'}
console.log(require('./b')); // {name: 'b'}
```

so, i can change a module exports from outside

if i cange the `a.js` to `a.json`

a.json

```
{
    "name": "a"
}
```

i got the same result

how can i export a module can't modify or override form outside

Answer (score 4):

You can freeze an object:

```
// in order for people to not add properties through the prototype
var o = Object.create(null);
o.name = 'a';
Object.freeze(o); // no one can change properties
Object.seal(o); // no one can add properties;
module.exports = o;
```

If you're using a modern version of nodejs (read io.js) you can also use a proxy:

```
var o = {name: 'a'};
var p = new Proxy(o, {
   set: function(obj, prop, value) {
       // unlike the freeze approach, this also throws in loose mode
       throw new TypeError("Can't set anything on this object");
   }
});
return p;
```

That said, who are you guarding against? Why would people change the object in another module?

Comment: thanks, i just curious is other language module has the same action like node?

Comment: @GilbertSun it's not another language, it's just "non-deprecated node", node runs on a really old version of JavaScript and isn't really being updated that much. io.js is where all the contributors went when they got sick of how node was running http://iojs.org/

Comment: @GilbertSun Yes, its called mutating an object. Its quite common in manu popular languages.